# Cannot browse a public URL hosted on EC2 from company VPN?

Tags: url, amazon-ec2, vpn

I have a public URL hosted from an Amazon EC2 instance. I can browse the URL successfully from anywhere, but not from my system when connected via company VPN.

I guess I am missing on some inbound rule to be configured in the respective security group.

Please help.

Comment: When using the VPN connection, can you access other sites on the Internet? What is the configuration of the Inbound security group on that Amazon EC2 instance? If you launch another instance (eg in your Default VPC), does it have the same problem?

Comment: > can you access other sites on the Internet?
yes very well.

> What is the configuration of the Inbound security group on that Amazon EC2 instance?
I have tried to open as much as possible across HTTP, TCP, ICMP, SSH - since I need to run some tests for a day or 2 (so overlooked security)

Comment: It might be in an IP range that is blocked by your corporate network. You should ask your Networking team if they block any ranges. If you launch another EC2 instance in your Default VPC, does it have the same problem?